# Excel VBA: Copying Worksheet to Existing Workbook (variable)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to store an active workbook as a variable so that I can call upon that same workbook even if the name changes. Then, I would like to open another workbook and copy the first sheet into the existing workbook.

Here is the relevant portion:

```
Dim WorkbookA As Workbook
     Set WorkbookA = ActiveWorkbook.Name


folder = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", 1, "Select file")
Workbooks.Open Filename:=folder

    NewFile = Dir(folder)
    Workbooks(NewFile).Activate

ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(1)
```

The error message I keep getting is related to setting WorkbookA to the active workbook.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Name` is a string (property) of the workbook object. So you'll get an error for sure on that line.

Simply: `Set workbookA = ActiveWorkbook`, instead. I'd also do:

```
Set workbookA = ActiveWorkbook

Dim otherWorkbook as Workbook

folder = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", 1, "Select file")
Set otherWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=folder)
workbookA.ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=otherWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to just switch otherWorkbook and workbookA in the last line because I want to copy the sheet from otherWorkbook to workbookA :)